# firebase email/password auth with REST API

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to do email/password auth with the REST API rather the SDKs? (without having to set up my own token server)

I can't find anything in the docs about it.

Comment: Nope. There is no public REST endpoint to authenticate users with email+password. Since this has been asked before, I'll find and mark as a duplicate.

Comment: Can't find the dupe, I'll just answer.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322747/using-mail-and-password-to-authenticate-via-the-rest-api-firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

There is no public REST endpoint to authenticate users with email+password (or any other supported provider). When using the REST API, you will have to either mint your own tokens, use your Firebase's secret or get the token from somewhere else (e.g. passed from a client app to your code).

Comment: do you mean hardcode the firebase's secret into the client? what's the downside to that in terms of security?

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen        Since Database secrets are currently deprecated, I suppose the only options available when using REST API are : mint your own tokens or request them from OAuth2.0 with a service account.

Comment: What about [Using mail and password to authenticate via the REST API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322747/using-mail-and-password-to-authenticate-via-the-rest-api-firebase)

Answer (score 1):

To Login
POST

`https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=<web-key>`

Request Body:

```
{
  "email": "email",
  "password": "password",
  "returnSecureToken": true
}
```

More on : [Firebase Auth Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth)

Comment: Any chance you've been able to get this working with the Authentication Emulator? I've tried replacing the domain with localhost:9099 but that doesn't work

Comment: @DavidRitchie any luck accomplishing this with the auth emulator?

Comment: @MikeG sorry not had the time to get back on to this yet. I believe the auth emulator has had a lot done to it recently and may be in the stable release soon too.

Comment: no worries @DavidRitchie I opened a question yesterday but was able to figure it out shortly after https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66342941/firebase-auth-emulator-email-password-sign-in-rest-endpoint/66343248#66343248

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it! No idea why firebase docs are so retarded for REST. I checked how app generated with this https://github.com/firebase/generator-angularfire . And it uses REST in several cases. Dig deeper. I don't know about all params in this methods, but it works.

To login

```
GET
<url to your firebase instanse>/auth/password?&email=<email>&password=<password>&v=js-2.2.2&transport=json&suppress_status_codes=true
```

To sign up

```
POST
<url to your firebase instanse>/users?&email=<email>&password=<password>&_method=POST&v=js-2.2.2&transport=json&suppress_status_codes=true
```