# Firebase Auth Emulator email/password Sign In REST endpoint

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I'm able to use this endpoint `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[API-KEY]` (found in [these docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth) @ section *Sign In With Email / Password*) to sign in a Firebase Authentication user via an HTTP request.

Is there anyway to accomplish this on the Firebase Authentication Emulator - is there an emulator REST endpoint which will serve the same function?

When I run the auth emulator on port 9099 I've tried - 
. `http://localhost:9099/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[API-KEY]` 
. `http://localhost:9099/emulator/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[API-KEY]` 
. `http://identitytoolkit.localhost:9099/emulator/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[API-KEY]` 
. `http://localhost:9099/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=[API-KEY]`

But none work. Any ideas?

Here is the response I get for each of these requests -

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Not Found",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Not Found",
                "reason": "notFound"
            }
        ],
        "status": "NOT_FOUND"
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Also tried this:
`http://localhost:9099/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/projects/emulator-test-project-id/accounts?key=[API-KEY]`

but get the response

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION : Only authenticated requests can specify target_project_id.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION : Only authenticated requests can specify target_project_id.",
                "reason": "invalid",
                "domain": "global"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This one works -

`http://localhost:[PORT]/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[API-KEY]`

where `API-KEY` can be any string and 9099 is the `PORT` on which the auth emulator is running. For me it defaults to 9099 but you can configure this via your `firebase.json` ([more details here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure))

**EDIT March 19 2024:**
you may need to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` as I think a recent firebase-tools update may have caused an issue with using localhost

Comment: This isn't documented anywhere that I can find, and seems to work. Thank you.

Comment: This URL template also works for signUp for creating accounts on the fly.

Comment: Lifesaver! Thank you MikeG !

Comment: This should really be mentioned in the docs...

Comment: super useful! all endpoints from identitytoolkit.googleapis.com are working on my side

Comment: Note, that the part of the URL `...accounts:<action>` is case sensitive.

Comment: This is working ! What a shame this is not documented anywhere...

Comment: For me, the host needs to be 127.0.01, not "localhost".
Sending the same data as to the live endpoint, the emulator gave me "Bad Request" (password, email, returnSecureToken), turns out the emulator cares about the correct "application/json" header while the online version doesn't.

Comment: MikeG how did you discover this endpoint?

Comment: @loweryjk was a long time ago but I think I just used web console to inspect the url that the Firebase SDK was hitting